# Jsoup 1.7.1 bug?

Tags: java, jsoup

Execution of the following code:

`Jsoup.connect(baseURL + dataJSSrc).execute();`

throws an Exception:

```
org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException: Unhandled content type. Must be text/*, application/xml, or application/xhtml+xml. Mimetype=application/x-javascript, URL=http://www.abc.com/playdata/206/8910.js?44613.77
```

but when I use

`URLConnection conn = new URL(baseURL + dataJSSrc).openConnection();`

it is OK!

in the following code

```
System.out.println(conn.getContentType()); // out put 'application/x-javascript'
```

Can Jsoup only be used to download HTML or XML?

Answer (score 8):

Whilst I don't disagree with BalusC's answer, you can use Jsoup to download anything you like. By default, Jsoup will throw an exception if it retrieves content with a mime type that it will not be able to parse as HTML, to avoid parsing e.g. images. However you can disable that test with `connection.ignoreContentType(true)` if you just want to get at the bytes or as a string:

```
String script = Jsoup.connect(jsUrl).ignoreContentType(true).execute().body();
```

or

```
byte[] bytes = Jsoup.connect(imageUrl).ignoreContentType(true).execute().bodyAsBytes();
```

You will get more control with a full-fledged HTTP client, but this method can be useful in a pinch.

Answer (score 1):

Jsoup is designed as a HTML/XML parser, not as a pure HTTP client. If you need to download some non-HTML/XML files, then rather use a normal HTTP client, not a HTML/XML parser.

Something with using the right tool for the job.